# JavaScript | AngularJS: Filter Items by Date-Filter Result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

#### Filter Items by Date-Filter Result

Inside of `ng-repeat` a `createdAt` property gets filtered using the `| date` filter. Within the `ng-repeat`, `item in items` gets `| filter`ed by `term`. In other words, my code looks something like this:

```
<input placeholder="search" ng-model="term" />

<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:term">
    {{item.createdAt | date}}
</div>
```

Pretty basic. The `date` filter takes the (ISO?) date of `2015-09-03T00:12:43.107Z` and returns something like `Sep 2, 2015`.

**Desired Scenario:**

An `item` displays the filtered `createdAt` text of, say, *Sep 2, 2015*.
User searches for "2" -- and reduces the array-results down to display only those items whose **filtered by date result** matches their criteria.

The user just accomplished filtering items down by *date* -- but more importantly, filtered items down **by what date was visible to the user** based upon the `date` filter's return value.

Is there a way to accomplish this without writing a custom filter -- or need I use a filter that utilizes `$filter('filter')` & `$filter('date')`?

Maybe something like:

```
item in items | filter:{date: (term | date:'ISO'), name: term}
// converts term back to ISO for matching (ideally)
```

<s>I suppose this should also know if `term` *is* a date before attempting to filter it as such because `term` should also filter `items` if there is a match on `item.name` as well.</s>
*EDIT: You can run a text value through the `date` filter and have the same value returned.*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What Worked For Me

As my need was to keep complexity low while aligning the implementation as much as possible with the native `filter` functionality -- I arrived at the following:

Without filtering on *displayed date*:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text" ng-model="q" />
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:q">{{order.createdAt | date:'short'}}</li>
</ul>
```

Filtering upon displayed date (and anything else):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="text" ng-model="q" />
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:q" ng-init="order['|'] = { createdAt: (order.createdAt | date:'short') }">{{order['|'].createdAt}}</li>
</ul>
```

This worked great as I didn't have to specialize *anything* -- simply initialize the iteration with an additional property (underneath the `|` namespace) which Angular would automatically filter against when the user's input changes. Now the User can **filter by what they see** or by any other property just the same.

Cheers!